Limiting delimiters when importing a .txt file
Here I am again asking about VBA, Sometimes we receive data from one of our payment partners that has extra unnecessary comma in consumers first name and suffixes for example Jr. Sr. and etc. How can i put a condition in my code to limit this?
This is an example of a data from the.txt file with extra commas:
15-1503-0533,BARONA, VIRGILIO, JR.,202403,2024-03-21 19:50:59.000,972.26,0.00,0.00,08,A3E71D1641E8
When I import the file in Excel it looks like this:

The column should end in "J" but since the first name and suffix has a comma between them, the code separates the data automatically.
here's my current code
Sub ImportTextFile()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim qt As QueryTable
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set targetCell = ws.Range("A5")
    
    filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If filePath = "False" Then Exit Sub
    ws.Cells.Clear
    
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & filePath, Destination:=targetCell)
    With qt
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .Refresh
    End With

    insert_cell
End Sub

What condition can I add to my code that would automatically disregard commas that separates the first name and suffix?
I am hoping to have a result like this when uploading a .txt file with extra commas in their suffixes:

Any help is appreciated!

I can't simply remove the comma one by one because we have so much data coming in everyday from paying customers. And the data being sent to us is also computer-generated from their database

"computer-generated from their database" if values containing the field separator aren't quoted to prevent this exact type of problem then your customer's systems are just bad...

With modifying the insert_cell Sub, pls. try this:
Sub insert_cell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set targetRange = ws.Range("A5").CurrentRegion
    
    For Each rw In targetRange.Rows
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rw.Row, "J")) Then
            ws.Cells(rw.Row, "C").Insert xlToRight
        End If
        If Not IsNumeric(ws.Cells(rw.Row, "D")) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rw.Row, "K")) Then
            ws.Cells(rw.Row, "C") = ws.Cells(rw.Row, "C") & " " & ws.Cells(rw.Row, "D")
            ws.Cells(rw.Row, "D").Delete xlShiftToLeft
        End If
    Next rw

End Sub

It assumes that the name and suffix is followed with a number and all the other data are set to a value in the row. (means that column K has a value).
Another workaround can be to list all the acceptable suffixes in an array and compare them to the fourth value in a row and then do the correction.


QueryTables can't indentify the data with different patterns
I would suggest to clean the unexpected data with a Sub. Then call it in your main Sub as below.

Call CleanData(ws.Range("A5"))

Sub CleanData(StartCell As Range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Const COL_CNT = 10 ' modify as needed
    Const COL_KEY = 4
    Set rngData = StartCell.CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    If UBound(arrData, 2) > COL_CNT Then
        For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
            ' COL_KEY is not a number
            If Not IsNumeric(arrData(i, COL_KEY)) Then
                ' merge cell with left cell
                arrData(i, COL_KEY - 1) = arrData(i, COL_KEY - 1) & _
                    " " & arrData(i, COL_KEY)
                ' Shift cells to left
                For j = COL_KEY To UBound(arrData, 2) - 1
                    arrData(i, j) = arrData(i, j + 1)
                Next j
                arrData(i, UBound(arrData, 2)) = ""
            End If
        Next i
        rngData.Value = arrData
    End If
End Sub

